# How to create select box from a table and query a <td> with jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, select, html-table

Essentially I am trying to recreate the functionality seen at the bottom of www.hurtta.com for a client. They have a list of dogs, products and size for each dog and product.  I was given the data in an Excel spreadsheet (yuck) I was able to save it off as an html table and strip all of the fluff classes and id's that come from Excel. But now I have just under 13,000 lines of code for a table. Each Excel row now looks like this:

```
 <tr >
  <td>Hurtta Collars</td>
  <td>Thai Ridgeback</td>
  <td>55, 60</td>
 </tr>
```

I need to figure out how to take the first td and create a select box with these values, same for the second td and when a selection is made the third row value appears all jquery snazzy.  Any thoughts, ideas, suggestions? Again, there are over 2500 tr's like the one you see above.

Comment: Might help http://lightswitch05.github.io/table-to-json/

Comment: So you want a dropdown box with... 13,000 entries...? And what do you mean by 'jQuery snazzy'?

Comment: forget snazzy, it was just an expression. No there are 13k lines of code. The drop downs will contain about 150 items and 20 items respectively.